# Increment number in string

Tags: python

I am trying to get the following output until a certain condition is met.

```
test_1.jpg
test_2.jpg
..
test_50.jpg
```

The solution (if you could remotely call it that) that I have is

```
fileCount = 0
while (os.path.exists(dstPath)):
   fileCount += 1
   parts = os.path.splitext(dstPath)
   dstPath = "%s_%d%s" % (parts[0], fileCount, parts[1])
```

however...this produces the following output.

```
test_1.jpg
test_1_2.jpg
test_1_2_3.jpg
.....etc
```

The Question: How do I get change the number in its current place (without appending numbers to the end)?

Ps. I'm using this for a file renaming tool.

---

UPDATE: Using various ideas below, i've discovered a loop that works

```
dstPathfmt = "%s_%d%s"
parts = os.path.splitext(dstPath)
fileCount = 0
while (os.path.exists(dstPath)):
   fileCount += 1
   dstPath = parts[0]+"_%d"%fileCount+parts[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to keep dstPath something like "test_%d.jpg", and just pass it a varying count:

```
dstPath = "test_%d.jpg"
i = 1
while os.path.exists(dstPath % i):
    i += 1
dstPath = dstPath % i # Final name
```

Comment: a very interesting idea...however i need the flexibility of changing any part of the filename to reflect the original.

However, I did change my algorithm above to include a little of both your answer and the answer below.


now have

dstPathfmt = "%s_%d%s"
parts = os.path.splitext(dstPath)
fileCounter = 0 #to match the first file "test.jpg"
while (os.path.exists(dstPath)):
    fileCounter += 1
    dstPath = parts[0]+"_%d"%fileCount+parts[1]

Answer (score 1):

Print out the value of parts[0] each time you go round the loop ... I think you may be surprised,

Comment: I think i fixed the problem.

I moved 

parts = os.path.splitext(dstPath)

outside of the while loop.  works perfectly now.

Comment: yes, as per Michael's suggestion. You do understand why your version didn't I hope?

Comment: i think it is because as each loop executed, dstPath changed (because the previous loop had modified it).  Moving it outside used the dstPath before it changed by the loop.

Comment: Yes, but **how** did it change? First time round part[0] is file-1, you then added -2 to that, so next time round part[0] is file-1-2. You thought that fileCount was screwy, but it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your condition `os.path.exists(dstPath)` is matching the same renamed file multiple times. So for example, it renames test.jpg to test_1.jpg; then renames test_1.jpg to test_1_2.jpg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in range(1,10):
    print("test_{0}.jpg".format(j))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLv8t.png)

Comment: Yes,  it renames test.jpg to test_1.jpg; then renames test_1.jpg to test_1_2.jpg, etc.
You can see the output of the code by clicking the given link.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Python v3.6+ - using [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
for n in range(1,51):
    print(f'test_{n}')
```